# Update contact in Google People API

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I'm having trouble updating the notes of contacts through Googles People API. I used some code from a previous stackoverflow answer, but it doesn't seem to work anymore. Below is the function I'm using. I'm attempting to change the notes of a particular contact to "changed bio xyz".

What am I doing wrong? The api does read a listing of the contacts, but I haven't been able to successfully write yet.

Thanks and please let me know if I can make this question more clear

```
results = service.people().connections().list(
    resourceName='people/me',
    pageSize=1500,
    personFields='names,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,biographies').execute()
connections = results.get('connections', [])


aContact = service.people().get(
resourceName = 'people/c1589313158061148817',
personFields = 'biographies' ).execute()
notesNames = aContact['biographies'][0]        
notesNames['value'] = 'changed bio xyz'

result = service.people().updateContact(
resourceName = 'people/c1589313158061148817',
body = aContact, 
updatePersonFields = 'biographies'
).execute()
```

Comment: Why do you have the results and connection on the top? Is it related to what you are trying to do?

Comment: I took this from stock python code from googles documentation. I’m just trying to control one change at a time and I don’t really understand what’s necessary in calling the API. I find the documentation a little confusing.

Comment: Have you tried using it on [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fc1589313158061148817%22%2C%22updatePersonFields%22%3A%22biographies%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22biographies%22%3A%5B%7B%22value%22%3A%22Example%22%2C%22contentType%22%3A%22TEXT_PLAIN%22%7D%5D%7D%7D&apix=true)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The update goes in the `body` section, and it needs to follow a dictionary format

```
  aContact = service.people().get(
resourceName = 'people/c36943406266964946',
personFields = 'names,nicknames'
).execute()
print ('this is acontact', aContact)
NickNames = aContact['nicknames'][0]        
NickNames['value'] = 'newNickName'

aContact['nicknames'] = NickNames
result = service.people().updateContact(
resourceName = 'people/c36943406266964946',
body = aContact, 
updatePersonFields = 'nicknames'
).execute()
```